# Nuget pacakage (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer) can not found

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, visual-studio-2019, nuget-package, entity-framework-core-3.1

I'm trying to add "Microsoft Entity Frame work Core SQL Server" package to my project dependencies(using Visual studio 2019) but its keep telling me package not found every time i search..please is their another way i can get this package install in my project because in can not proceed using database without this package install as i was taught.

---

[This is the image of what I use to get when i search for it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rSHR.jpg)

Comment: It seems like you search in "Microsoft Visual Studio offline packages" only. You can change that to "All" (it is the dropdown on the right site)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you have set your package source wrongly. Change from "Offline Packages" to "All" maybe.

Comment: After select All...  I still get another messsage says "[Package source] Unable to load the service index for source http://packagesource.
  An error occurred while sending the request.
  The remote name could not be resolved: 'packagesource'"

Comment: This is the source URL. https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json. Click on the settings icon and change it from there.